# Удаление элемента из ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня есть класс `Worker` и форма расчета ЗП

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Worker extends Object {
private String full_name;
private String position;
private int pay;
private String string_pay;
public Worker (String worker_full_name, String worker_position, int worker_pay){
    full_name = worker_full_name;
    position = worker_position;
    pay = worker_pay;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return full_name + " - " + position + " - " + pay + " руб" + "\n";
}
public int getPay(){
   int result = pay;
   return result;
   }
}
```

Я храню информацию о каждом сотруднике в `ArrayList workers`. 
Добавляю новых рабочих, получая `ФИО,` `Должность` и `ЗП` из полей формы.

```
   Worker worker = new Worker(full_name_Text_Field.getText(),position_list_model.getSelectedItem().toString(),worker_pay);
            workers.add(worker);
  // добавляем строку с новым рабочим в текстовое поле
  list_of_workers.setText(list_of_workers.getText()+ workers.get(workers.size()-1).toString());
```

При нажатии на кнопку "удалить" происходит следующие:

```
   if (e.getSource() == delete_button && list_of_workers.getText().trim().length() > 0) {

   // запоминаем выделенный текст
   str_on_delete = list_of_workers.getSelectedText();
   // Разделяем его на строки и записываем в массив (нужно если выделили несколько строк)
    String [] strs = new String[str_on_delete.split("\n").length];
            strs = str_on_delete.split("\n");
            // Сравниваем каждого worker с выделенными строками
            for (int i =0; i< str_on_delete.split("\n").length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<workers.size(); j++){
                    // Если получаем совпадение
                    if (workers.get(j).toString().equals(strs[i]) ){
                       // удаляем рабочего из ArrayList 
                       workers.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
                        // Очищаем текстовое поле от выделенного текста
                        list_of_workers.replaceSelection("");
                        // проверяем удалился ли рабочий
                        System.out.println(workers.size());
        }
```

Почему объект не удаляется из `ArrayList workers`?

Comment: Вы уверены, что equals выдаёт равенство? В Worker \n явно включено, а в strs по \n как раз разделение происходит.

Comment: @hinotf спасибо, вы правы.